# Save results from sqlite3_exec callback function into a dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, closures

I want to create a function which executes `sqlite3_exec` and saves the results into a dictionary object which is passed as parameter. For that I have created following code:

```
func execute(sql: String, result: inout Dictionary<String, String>) {
    let rc = sqlite3_exec(
        dbPointer,    // database
        sql,          // statement
        {             // callback: non-capturing closure
            resultVoidPointer, columnCount, values, columns in

            for i in 0 ..< Int(columnCount) {
                let value = String(cString: values![i]!)
                let column = String(cString: columns![i]!)
                result[column] = value         // Error: Escaping closures can only capture inout parameters explicitly by value
                print("\(column) = \(value)")
            }
            return 0
        },
        nil,
        nil
    )

    if rc != SQLITE_OK {
        print("SQLite Error: " + errorMessage)
    }
}
```

But this code gives me following error: `Escaping closures can only capture inout parameters explicitly by value`. Another attempt would be to have the function `execute` return a dictionary object, but then the error message becomes: `A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Er. Why not use the normal prepared statement api and loop while `sqlite3_step()` returns `SQLITE_ROW`? That's how you'd do it in C, and the Swift bindings seen almost identical from what I've seen.

Comment: I thought this would be the easier solution. Could you provide code where `sqlite3_exec()` is replaced with `prepare`, `step` and `finalize`, so that my `execute` function can take an arbitrary sql statements and create a dictionary with column:value as key:value pair?

Comment: I don't know about any swift-specific documentation because I've never used the language, but the correspondence with C functions seems to refreshingly be mostly one to one, and that workflow and relevant functions is described here: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html

Comment: Plus what you're doing doesn't really make sense... If it worked you'd be overwriting the same records in the dictionary with every row and only ending up with the last rows values. That seems unlikely to be what you want unless your query only returns one row.

Comment: Yeah just realized that too. I would probably need an array of dictionaries where I append a new dictionary element each time the callback gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9952196/shawn)'s comments, I created a new version of `execute`, where I using `sqlite3_prepare_v2`, `sqlite3_step` and `sqlite3_finalize` instead of the combined function `sqlite3_exec`:

```
func prepare(sql: String) -> OpaquePointer? {
    var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil
    guard sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbPointer, sql, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
        print(errorMessage)
        return nil
    }
    return statement
}


func execute(sql: String) -> [Dictionary<String, String>] {
    var result: [Dictionary<String, String>] = []

    guard let queryStatement = prepare(sql: sql) else {
        return result
    }

    defer {
        sqlite3_finalize(queryStatement)
    }

    while sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_ROW {
        var dictionary: Dictionary<String, String> = [:]

        for i in 0...sqlite3_column_count(queryStatement)-1 {
            let column: String = String(cString: sqlite3_column_name(queryStatement, i))
            let value: String = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, i))
            dictionary[column] = value
        }

        result.append(dictionary)
    }

    guard sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_DONE else {
        print(errorMessage)
        return result
    }

    return result
}
```

My `execute` function now returns an array of dictionaries, where each dictionary represents a row for SQL statements like SELECT. For other SQL statements like INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE, where no rows will be returned, the function `execute` returns an empty array.

After executing a SQL statement the result can be accessed by

```
let result = execute(db, "SELECT id, name, age FROM Table")
print(result[i][age])      // prints the value in row i and column age
```